# Android Layout Elements positions

Tags: android, xml

I want first element center and second is right of the layout. 
My result is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/joxAV.jpg
But I need this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F73py.jpg
this is my layout code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/colorAccent"
android:minWidth="100dp"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Do" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="20dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/food_selected_remove_button"
        android:gravity="right" />
  </LinearLayout>
```

how change layout? (parent Layout Type not important.Linear or Relative).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this:**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent"
    android:minWidth="100dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:weightSum="10">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="24dp"
        android:layout_weight="9"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
        android:text="Do" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="20dp"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
            android:background="@drawable/food_selected_remove_button" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**OUTPUT:**

[image]

Comment: Happy to help :)